# Does this sentence sound odd?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-structure

> "Hello Dears,
> Please review the email below, as what is advised to do
> so.

I've mixed feelings about the end of this sentence. "Do so."
Shouldn't be: to do.
It is the first sentence of the email(the rest describes what we need to do). This is, I believe, a second request.

Comment: 'to do so' is a fixed phrase. For now, you can consult https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/so (scroll down until you see a blue box)

Comment: This is proofreading, which is off-topic, but I will tell you _gratis_ that "Hello Dears" is something you would write to little children.

Comment: @Nameless Thank you. What I read on this forum is that to do so helps avoid redundancy.  But in this case, he mentioned "to do so" before what to do so actually is

Comment: @Michael Harvey, I agree as a recipient of this email, feel that way.

Comment: No, it is mentioned what to do. 'It is advised to do so' means 'It is advised to **review the email below**'.

Comment: @Nameless. Ahh, now I see it. Yeah, I was looking at it wrongly. Thank you very much for help

Comment: @Nameles One question, if I may. If to do so phrase refers to " review the email below,"  why there is the phrase "as what is advised "?

"Please review the email below, as what is advised to do"  means that review this email as it explains what you need to do.

In the first example (with to do so) I cannot see the semantic sense. Can you please explain it?

Comment: Are you advising the readers of the message to review the email, or telling them that it contains advice?

Comment: @Kate Bunting Hi Kate. I was a receiver. I tried to figure out what they are advising me to do.

Comment: The message was obviously written by someone with very poor English, so I wouldn't like to guess what they meant.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is obviously written by someone with a poor grasp of English and hence hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because nobody is going to answer, here's mine.

'Please review the email below, as what is advised to do so' is ungrammatical. The other two possibilities I can think of:

1. Please review the email below, as what is advised **is** to do so.
2. Please review the email below, as **it** is advised to do so.

Note that, when *what* is used as a pronoun, it means '[the thing(s) that](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/what)', so we have 'Please review the email below, as **the thing that** is advised is to do so'. Also, '[to do so](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/so)' means 'to act in the way mentioned'. The way mentioned is 'review the email below', so we have 'Please review the email below, as **the thing that** is advised is to **review the email below**'. How *what* is used in **1** is often referred to as [wh-cleft sentences](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/cleft-sentences-it-was-in-june-we-got-married). In fact, my previous sentence is an example of it. As for **2**, *it* is nonreferential, which means 'without a referent'. In other words, it acts as a [dummy pronoun](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/it).

Comment: Thank you Nameless. It is exactly what was missing! Linking verb that helps reference to it.